# How to invoke 'trackball' tool with python?

Tags: python

Now I know press the <kbd>R</kbd> key twice to activate the trackball tool.

How can I invoke it with Python script?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

[bpy.ops.transform.trackball()](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.transform.html#bpy.ops.transform.trackball)

Comment: Oh, I already know it. But is there api such like this "bpy.ops.wm.tool_set_by_id(name="builtin.select_box")" ?